# Node.js: Sending file in same directory

Tags: linux, node.js

I hope this question isn't too ridiculous.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);


app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});

http.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('/','listening on *:3000');
});
```

I am running linux mint, and whenever I try to run this locally I get the following error:

> Error: ENOENT, stat 'index.html'
>       at Error (native)

I believe it has something to do with the directory. The `index.html` file is in the same folder as the `index.js` file. I've searched around and couldn't find this exact error in this case so am kind of confused. Am I putting in the wrong directory for the

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

Comment: Unless the root option is set in the options object, path must be an absolute path of the file. ([express docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile))

Comment: Hello thank you. I will read through this doc and try and understand exactly what that means. Very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify exactly where your index.html file is located. Try using the following code snippet

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require('path');


app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

http.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('/','listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you very much. Little confused exactly what is going on but will look at the docs to try and see. Again Thank you. Also I upvoted you but it isn't public. :/ sorry

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. Basically, what's happening is __dirname will tell your server the directory name of the currently executing script(which in your case is index.js). Then using path.join, we join the path name of the directory and the name of the file that you're trying to send(index.html). We can't just send the index.html file directly because the server doesn't know where to look for the file you're trying to send(even though they're both in the same directory). That's just how servers work. You should definitely look into the docs because it can be a little confusing at first.